# uncaught reference error Function not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

Simple program that will calculate a periodic interest rate, however the function is defined and called in a button but still the error for uncaught reference still shows. Much help is appreciated

```
function calculatePayment(){
        var loanAmount = document.getElementById("txtLoanAmount").value;
        var interestRate = document.getElementById("txtInterestRate").value;
        var amortiPeriod = document.getElementById("txtYearlyPeriod").value;
        var totalPayment;
        var numOfMonths;

        //Convert strings from text box to integers
        loanAmount = parseInt(loanAmount);
        interestRate = parseInt(interestRate);
        amortiPeriod = parseInt(amortiPeriod);
        //Validate the input boxes to ensure values were added and follow application rules
        if (loanAmount == null || loanAmount == ""){
            //alert("You must enter a loan amount");
            message = "You must enter a loan Amount";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
        }else if (interestRate == null || interestRate == ""){
            //alert("You must enter a interest rate");
            message = "You must enter an interest rate";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
        }else if (amortiPerid == null || amortiPeriod == ""){
            //alert("You must enter an interest rate");
            message = "You must enter an interest rate";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
         }else if isNaN(loanAmount || interestRate || amortiPeriod){
            message = "The values you enter must be numeric";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
         }else{
            numOfMonths = amortiPeriod * 12;
            paymentRate = loanAmount * interestRate / 100;
            totalPayment = paymentRate * numOfMonths;
            message = totalPayment;
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
         }

    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
                <td><input type="button" onClick="calculatePayment()" name="btnCalculate" value="Calculate Payment"/></td><td><input type="button" name="btnClear" value="Clear"/></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML section

Comment: *Where* is the function defined? If it is not available in the global scope, then the DOM cannot run it in an `onclick`. You can add after the function def: `window.calculatePayment = calculatePayment`.

Comment: I spot errors, like `} else if isNaN( ...` where the parentheses are completely missing

Comment: `amortiPeriod !== amortiPerid`, learn to type, and this stuff gets a lot easier.

Comment: FYI when I get to `if else if` my 'refactor' alarm sounds off when I write code

Comment: As this smells like homework, I updated with a partially working answer; you have to fix the rest

Answer (score 2):

unexpected identifier:

```
  } else if isNaN(loanAmount || interestRate || amortiPeriod) {
```

With this markup (since you provide less than needed)

```
<input id="calcme" type="button" name="btnCalculate" value="Calculate Payment" />
<input type="button" name="btnClear" value="Clear" />
<input type="text" id="txtInterestRate" value="10">int
<input type="text" id="txtLoanAmount" value="1200">amt
<input type="text" id="txtYearlyPeriod" value="1"> years per
<div id="errorMessage">
  errors
</div>
```

You would need to revise this partially working code to solve your real problems here:

```
function showError(message) {
  document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = message;
}

function showLoanAmount(amount) {
  document.getElementById("txtLoanAmount").value = amount;
}

function showInterestRate(rate) {
  document.getElementById("txtInterestRate").value = rate;
}

function showYearlyPeriod(period) {
  document.getElementById("txtLoanAmount").value = period;
}

function getLoanAmount() {
  return parseInt(document.getElementById("txtLoanAmount").value);
}

function getInterestRate() {
  return parseInt(document.getElementById("txtInterestRate").value);
}

function getYearlyPeriod() {
  return parseInt(document.getElementById("txtLoanAmount").value);
}

function calculatePayment() {
  // get values
  var loanAmount = getLoanAmount();
  var interestRate = getInterestRate();
  var amortiPeriod = getYearlyPeriod();
  var totalPayment;
  var numOfMonths;
  var message = "";

  //set values
  showLoanAmount(loanAmount);
  showInterestRate(interestRate);
  showYearlyPeriod(amortiPeriod);
  //Validate the input boxes to ensure values were added and follow application rules
  if (!loanAmount) {
    message = "You must enter a loan Amount";
    showError(message);
  }
  if (!interestRate) {
    message = "You must enter an interest rate";
    showError(message);
  }
  if (!amortiPeriod) {
    message = "You must enter an interest rate";
    showError(message);
  }
  if (isNaN(loanAmount) || isNaN(interestRate) || isNaN(amortiPeriod)) {
    message = "The values you enter must be numeric";
    showError(message);
  }
  // crappy math here
  numOfMonths = amortiPeriod * 12;
  paymentRate = loanAmount * interestRate / 100;
  totalPayment = paymentRate * numOfMonths;
  message = totalPayment;
  showError(message);

}
var el = document.getElementById("calcme");
el.addEventListener("click", calculatePayment, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code:

```
else if isNaN(loanAmount || interestRate || amortiPeriod)
```

Should be checking each variable to determine if it is not a number, for example: `isNaN(loanAmount) || isNaN(interestRate) || isNaN(amortiPeriod)`

As an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zpep0t1q/1/

Also this line has a typo:

```
} else if (amortiPerid == null || amortiPeriod == ""){
```

`amortiPerid` is not `amortiPeriod`.